# using phpunit command line arguments in my tests/bootstrap/setup/etc

Tags: php, bash, phpunit, command-line-interface

I want to be able to print some config data to stdout from my tests *only* when I use the '--verbose' phpunit command line argument.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably this is not really intended by the authors of PHPUnit, but you can do it like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';

class EnvironmentTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testHasParam()
    {
      if (in_array('--verbose', $_SERVER['argv']))
         echo "lots of info";
      else
         echo "no info";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah yes, the good old $_SERVER var works on the CLI too. Cool. Just what I needed. Understood about the author's intention. I have one test case that checks the basic app env and sometimes I want to know the details. I think it's pretty nifty to do it this way. Thanks!